# BeautifulSoup: not getting content from within multiple <div> levels

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This issue has been asked here before, but the solutions offered have not resolved my issue, which is this: I am attempting to scrape a link from an internal company server (I cannot, therefore provide a direct link - sorry) that is comprised of many div layers. Basically, this:

```
<main id="main">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-group">
        <div class="nav-item">
        <!-- last div displayed in output -->
        <div class="nav-content"
             data="mass data chunk here, is this the problem?">
            <div style="display: none">
            <div class="list-view">
                <div class="list-results">
                <div class="list-panel">
                    <div class="list-content">
                    <ol class="issue-list">
                        <li data-key'"xxxx">
                        <!-- target -->
                        <a href="yyyy">zzz</a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div id="criteria"> <!-- next output displayed -->
            # more div's here, but not in ouptut
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

The code is simple:

```
out_a = soup.find_all('a')
out_div = soup.find_all('div')
print(out_a)
print(out_div)
```

Output:

```
# print(out_a)
[] 
# print(out_div)
<div class="container">
<div class="nav-group">
<div class="nav-item">
<div class="nav-content">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="criteria">
</div>
```

For reasons unknown to me, I am unable to travers beyond four `div` levels in the main block. As noted above, the final div I can see has a massive amount of data within the `div / data` tag. Could that be the issue?

Please note, I am new to BeautifulSoup, so the solution might be obvious but completely eluding me.

Regards.

Comment: If the URL is a private url within the company, you probably need to use a web-driver (selenium) to get past authentication and/or dynamically generated content

Comment: Could the website be using Javascript? Beautifulsoup is unable to handle JS, as it is dynamically loaded, and BS only deals with static content

Comment: Do you see the lower levels when you use `View Source` in the browser? If not, it's generated dynamically.

Comment: I can access and see all the page source via a GET request (the above code is from the response), so my auth credentials are provided.

Comment: @samsupertaco, yes, there are js scripts embedded throughout, but not in this particular section.

Comment: Html might be broken that even bs is not able to parse it correctly.

Comment: @LMC, the actual page loads fine in my browser. The fragment I posted is just that, a fragment.

Comment: BS is NOT a browser so it could still fail to parse the mess

Comment: @LMC, so how do I proceed? Any advice? I cannot change the page source.

Comment: you soup is correct, so likely the data is messing up the parsing. What do you get with `print(soup.find_all(class_="nav-content"))` ? [note the underscore after 'class']. You should get the div and all children.

Comment: I would suggest using a better parser like `lxml`with xpath

Comment: @pbuck, I get '[<div class="nav-content" data=""></div>]'

Comment: @kmt, that's your problem.. perhaps something in your data attribute is not strictly legal. You might try with subsets of the data to figure out what might be causing the parsing problem. You should be seeing <div class="nav-content" data="..."><div style="display: none"><div class="list-view"... etc., etc.